# Send value taken from AJAX to another PHP file via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL table with fields like `country code`, `state`, `postcode`, `city`. I want to create a form where when the user enters the country code `AU`, the state field should be filled with states that correspond to the country code. And when a state is selected, it should only show postcodes which are under the selected state. When a postcode is selected, the city for that value should be displayed on the city field.

Some rows from the database are:

```
| country | state | postcode | suburb    |
+---------+-------+----------+-----------+
| AU      | VIC   | 3000     | Melbourne |
| AU      | NSW   | 3006     | Sydney    |
```

So now I have this AJAX code which sends data to another PHP file:

```
function searchq5(){
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='ccd']").val();
    $.post("search-region.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(state){
        $("#state").html(state);
        searchq6();
    });
}

function searchq6(){
    var searchsub = $("input[name='region']").val();
    $.post("search-suburb.php", {searchVal: searchsub}, function(sbb){
        $("#sbb").html(sbb);
        searchq7();
    });
}
```

`search-region.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT state FROM `wp_locations` WHERE `country` LIKE '%".$searchq."%' ")or die("Could not search!");

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
        $output = '<option>No results!</option>';
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $state = $row['state'];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $state; ?>"><?php echo $state; ?></option>
            <?php
        } // while
    } // else
}
```

`search-suburb.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['searchsub'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['searchsub'];
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM `wp_locations` WHERE `state`='$searchq' ")or die("Could not search!");

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
        $output = '<option>No results!</option>';
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $suburb = $row['title'];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $suburb; ?>"><?php echo $suburb; ?></option>
            <?php
        } // while
    } // else
} // main if
```

My thinking here is, when a state is chosen, the value of that input box is sent to `select-suburb.php` as the search value. Nothing shows up as options for the suburbs. I don't get the results from the other PHP file. Can someone tell me a solution for this?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not so helpful. Please tell us if there are PHP errors or console errors showing

Comment: @mplungjan, edited the question. it simply searches for all the suburbs, and not the ones from the selected state

Comment: This looks strange: `WHERE \`state\`='$searchq'` - I would expect `WHERE state="'.$searchq.'"`

Comment: changed to what you said, still nothing @mplungjan

Comment: actually the problem is that nothing shows up as options. I don't get the results from the other php

Comment: So echo the actual SQL too to see what it translates to. It is likely just an SQL issue?

Comment: try echo the sql with it's passed value and manually query it on PHPmyadmin see if there's a result/row

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use the "async:false" option? As ajax requests are asynchronous the second method will be called before the request is done.

`$.ajaxSetup({async: false});`

Do your request, and after put:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
```

Comment: the functions are called in the callback